# coding Regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a regex pattern that filters out some specific values.

I tried running the pattern in PHP but it always returns NULL for values.

```
$re1='^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*?"(.*?/p/.*?,\d+,(\d+).*?)" "(\d+)" "(\d+)".*$';


preg_match($re1, $current_line, $matches);


var_dump($matches);
```

Sample $current_line variable value-

```
122.99.152.202 - naveen [22/Nov/2013:13:24:40 +1300] "GET /p/bhYg_TohdFLAxXoNBgIEbg,1385079896,119118112/12.txt HTTP/1.1" "302" "160" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

where am I doing wrong?

Comment: php requires delimeters for regexes: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: Nginx uses a compatible format with Apache combined format

Comment: @mcuadros I have a custom log format.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn : I tried replacing `/p/` with `\/p\/` but still returns NULL

Comment: A delimeter is the first and last characters, what you are talking about is escaping. A delimeter is what tells php where the start and end of the regular expression are at. Typically the forward slash (`/`) is used, but you can really use any non word character (with other popular characters being `@` and `~`). The point of using a delimeter other than `/` is that you then don't need to escape the `/` that are in the regex. **TLDR**, you can just put something like an `@` as the first and last character and it *should* work (I haven't tested the rest to see if it works).

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Great explanation. I just had to add `{` and `}` symbols. thanks a lot Jonathan Kuhn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no delimiters set in place for your regular expression.

A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.

You want to use a delimiter besides `/` so you can avoid having to escape `/`s in your pattern:

```
$re1 = '~^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*?"(.*?/p/.*?,\d+,(\d+).*?)" "(\d+)" "(\d+)".*$~';
```

See [working demo](https://eval.in/72178).

You can compact this a little bit if you wanted to.

```
$re1 = '~^((?:\d{1,3}\.?){4}).*?"(.*?/p/.*?,\d+,(\d+).*?)" "(\d+)" "(\d+)".*$~i';
```